# remove white screen which appears before splash screen

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I am using ionic4/angular and I have 2 problems. I have created a splash screen(animated logo) in separate page. When I open the app a white screen flicks before the splash screen (separate page) loads. I hide the splash screen. When I researched about this I found out that  it happens because the app itself taking time to load. Suggest an alternative way to achieve the same.

My second problem is a small line is appearing when logo is loading. This problem appears when deployed on real devices but it was perfect when i run on emulator and localhost. The small line looks like this:

[image]

but it shouldn't be like that.

```css
ion-content{
    --background:#FFBF00;
}
img{
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.tree {
    left: 0;
    right: 5%;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.tree > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFBF00;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation-name: hello;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: hello;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes hello {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 0%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hello {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
<div class="tree" text-center>
    <div></div>
    <img src="assets/logo.svg">
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall put a not animated version of the splashscreen in `YourAppFiles/resources`as `splash.png` (it has to be at least 2732×2732px) then run the command `ionic cordova ressources` to solve the first problem.

The second problem might be caused by how you made this "second splash screen" but without more code, I can't help you